# How can I limit a directory accessibility to only itself?

Tags: 16.04, security, directory, accessibility

**Here is the scenario:**

I have a wordpress project which is blog of my main project. Apparently that wordpress project contains a malware which edits js files and modifies the value of href links. Sadly that malware is deployed over the whole root. I mean that malware works on the js files of the main project too.

Now I want to know, how can I make that wordpress project isolated?
I want to limit accessibility of that wordpress project to only itself. To avoid publishing that malware (which exists in the wordpress project (which is a part of the main project)) in the whole main project?

I read somewhere, you can make a directory isolated on linux, like a different server. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read somewhere, you can make a directory isolated on linux, like a different server. Any idea how can I do that?

If you want to have an isolated directory, you can use **Chroot**. That makes you able to isolating applications from the rest of your computer.

For this purpose, please read this article: [BasicChroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot).

---

> how can I make that wordpress project isolated?

Also you use `chattr` command for making a directory and its contents immutable, even with root access.

```
sudo chattr -R +i /path/of/your/directory
```

After run above command any users can [change/remove/append] that directory and its constents.

And for remove immutable flag from that files, you can uses below command:

```
sudo chattr -R -i /path/of/your/directory
```

Comment: Just I'm not good in English and this `and its contents immutable` is vague for me. What do you mean exactly? It sounds to me like a *constant* file which files won't be modify at all. Right? While I want files to be editable, but no access to affect on other files out of that directory.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yes , immutable means that these files cannot be changed at all. If you want to make `to be editable, but no access to affect on others file` , you can use first method.

Comment: @Shafizadeh If its not be worked, please add more details like `what is that malware that affected your system`

Comment: Do you know what does *"so you shouldn't use chroot as a security measure to prevent a program from modifying files outside your simulated filesystem"* mean in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113) ?